# Fastlane storing screenshots AND test reports

Tags: xcode, fastlane, fastlane-snapshot

I have fastlane currently set up to run my UI Tests for my ios app in Xcode. Currently, I have a snapshot lane and a scan lane set up. One produces for me the screenshots I want as I run my UI Tests, while the other produces a xcpretty test report of which tests passed/failed.

My current issue is that to get both the screenshots and the report, I need to run both the scan and the snapshot lanes, which means I run the tests twice. Is there a way to only run the tests once while still producing both reports?

I have been looking for options in snapshot to produce a test report along with the screenshots, but I can't seem to find it if it exists.

Comment: Are your tests on xcode ui testing?

Comment: Yes, my code is on xcode ui testing.

Comment: Maybe you should try to make the screenshots directly on xcode test (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuiscreenshot), then generate the same html that snapshot does and execute all this through xcode test, while the test are been executed.